# Creating a matrix with extra row and column information in R

Tags: r, matrix, rows

I'm am trying to create a matrix of certain pairwise values, first by doing the calculations in a matrix and then melt it and join in some extra information. I would like to also include that extra information on the columns and rows so that I achieve something like the following if I convert it back into a matrix format (or data frame or whatever is possible):

```
                   X.col    1  2  3  4
                   Y.col    1  2  3  4
                   Z.col    1  2  3  4
                     Col    1  2  3  4
X.row  Y.row  Z.row  Row       
    1      1      1    1    1  0  0  1  
    2      2      2    2    0  1  0  0
    3      3      3    3    0  1  1  0
    4      4      4    4    0  1  0  1
```

or perhaps without the names, like this:

```
             1  2  3  4
             1  2  3  4
             1  2  3  4
             1  2  3  4    

1  1  1  1   1  0  0  1 
2  2  2  2   0  1  0  0
3  3  3  3   0  1  1  0
4  4  4  4   0  1  0  1
```

Basically x,y,z contain some extra information on some products which ID's are stored in row and col. I'm doing some pairwise comparisons which I then present in a matrix for our managers, who would also like to see that extra information along with the matrix as shown above.

So for the data, let a df contain the melted matrix joined with the extra information:

```
row = c(rep(1,4), rep(2,4), rep(3,4), rep(4,4)) #e.g. product id
col = rep(c(1,2,3,4), 4) #e.g. product id
value = c(1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1) #pairwise index value, calculated from comparing product in row with product in col
x.row = c(rep(1,4), rep(2,4), rep(3,4), rep(4,4)) #some x information on row id
y.row = c(rep(1,4), rep(2,4), rep(3,4), rep(4,4)) #some y information on row id
z.row = c(rep(1,4), rep(2,4), rep(3,4), rep(4,4)) #some z information on row id
x.col = rep(c(1,2,3,4), 4) #some x information on col id
y.col = rep(c(1,2,3,4), 4) #some y information on col id
z.col = rep(c(1,2,3,4), 4) #some z information on col id

df <- data.frame(row, col, value, x.row, y.row, z.row, x.col, y.col, z.col)
```

The question is then: **how to accomplish that matrix visual as shown above, or something like it in R?**

It is fairly easy to go about the issue in excel since it is cell-based, but I'm more interested in a solution in R (if possible). So I guess I'm looking for inspiration on how I might get about it, or maybe even a specific solution on how to do it. I've been thinking if it is possible using the openxlsx package, and manipulating a sheet in excel through R. Or maybe using lists, and storing them on the DF... Or heatmaply (which has an option for e.g. a dendrogram above a heatmap).

I must admit, however, I'm stuck. I can't get my head around it... So I guess I'm looking for your expertise :)

Comment: Not clear about the expected output

Comment: My first thought (if this is some form of sustainable "object") would be to start with a `matrix` as an object and attach an `attribute` with the two auxiliary matrices; this method really *presumes* that you would then generate helper functions that operate on this and maintain/update these aux matrices (something base functions will not do automatically). And then ... I wonder about what those ancillary matrices would actually store, and how they could be uesd. Perhaps you can provide some context, LRO? I wonder if a different structure might serve you better.

Comment: @akrun As I wrote above: Some managers would like to see the matrix with some extra information on top,  as conceptually shown. It is easy to do in Excel. Is there a way in R?

Comment: @r2evans It might be that another structure might serve me better. It sounds very complicated the way to conceptually describe.